# How can I connect the DVP camera output with Raspberry Pi or other MCU?

Tags: raspberry-pi, digital-communications, video

I have a MT9V034 image sensor module and I want to use its 8-bit DVP output. Does anyone know how to connect a DVP interface with a Raspberry Pi and show some graph?

I have read the Raspberry Pi user manual and it seems that its camera interface does not support DVP. Do you have any advice, or can you recommend another MCU for DVP connection?

And can you give me some links to learn about DVP interface? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. Raspberry Pi supports a MIPI D-PHY input.

The news is not all bad however. There are [many](https://www.pcguide.com/raspberry-pi/guide/best-camera/) excellent [camera solutions](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/camera-module-v2/) available for it that follow its cabling format and are supported with software drivers.

Other MCUs worth using are also going to use MIPI.

Meanwhile, the [MT9V034](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mt9v034-d.pdf) is on ‘lifetime buy’ status, and uses an interface (DVP parallel pixel) that is essentially obsolete.

Why bother? Get a different sensor.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by DVP being "essentially obsolete", please? Are ESP32-CAM and ESP-EYE obsolete? I mean, ESP-EYE was launched in 2021, And I believe ESP32 is still one of the most popular boards for IoT.

Comment: Newer sensors are MIPI.